# how to send a post request?

Tags: asp.net, c, json, web-services, post

How to consume web post service in C#? I did tests with POSTMAN and I got a response data, but in .net my response is empty. It works great in PostMan. The problem is how to format the Body Content and send it.

```
            string idop = "";
            List<ProductJSON> listProductsJSON = new List<ProductJSON>();
            List<List<string>> productJSON = new List<List<string>>();

            List<string> products = new List<string>();
            products.Add("4");
            products.Add("5");
            products.Add("30.2");
            products.Add("1");
            products.Add("0");
            products.Add("4");
            productJSON.Add(products);

using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var res = client.PostAsync("http://xyz.cti.lat/sant2/webservices/edd.php",
                  new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                    new {
                        a = "pCatlog",
                        cnal = "RED",
                        tpo = "2",
                        fpago = "DETO",
                        pgdo = "0",
                        rc = "13123",
                        local = "BACK",
                        localorg = "BACK",
                        raz = "PPPPPP",
                        dir_ruc = "name",
                        log = "CREAVIR",
                        not = "DETO2",
                        del = "0",
                        dir = "",
                        ubi = "",
                        refe = "",
                        prod = productJSON
                    }),
                    Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")));

                try
                {
                    res.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    var x = res;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: I'm confused. Is the question about consuming a post request, or handling the return from a post request? Or how to send a post request? Or...what?

Comment: consuming a post request

Comment: Ok. Can you post your code from where you've tried so far?

Comment: that's all, is my code correct?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code inside of the try block?

```
if (res.IsCompleted)
{
    var result = res.Result;
    var response = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var data = response.Result;
}
```

The ideal would be to declare this as an async method and use the await operations to get the result as follows.

```
var res = await client.PostAsync(<url>, <string_content>);         
var result = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```